# How to delete both cells if they contain the same information in Excel

Tags: excel

Hi I'm trying to delete(or minus, source 1 minus source 2) cells, if the cells contain the same information from two different source.
For example,

[image: Please click here for example]

Is any functions I can use to get the result?
(I was thinking to use `IF()` function and `VLOOKUP()` to show if there is a match, then fiter all the match, delete them. But that won't be reasonable, if some products display more than one times from both sources)

Comment: But in result column there are still dublicates left. Why they weren't deleted?

Comment: If there are duplicates left in result column, it means something wrong with source 1 or source 2. So I'll need to check those transaction detail. But logically, result shouldn't have duplicate cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, put this formula into cell `E3` :

```
=IF(COUNTIF($C$3:$C$10,A3)>=COUNTIF($A$3:A3,A3),"",A3)
```

Then result will be like this:

[image: 1]

However, if you want to eliminate empty cells, put this formula into cell `F3`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($E$3:$E$17,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($E$3:$E$17)-ROW($E$3)+1)/($E$3:$E$17<>""),ROWS(F$3:F3))),"")
```

Then final result will be this:

[image: 1]